# Problems with an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a big problem with my fetch and really don't know where my mistake is.

The problem is in the viewWillAppear function where I load my stuff into the tableView and this is the code:

```
NSNotificationCenter * theCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

NSFetchedResultsController *theController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

NSError *theError = nil;

theController.delegate = self;
//everything fine
self.fetchedResultsController = theController;
//program stops
if(![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&theError]) {
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad: %@", theError);
}

[theCenter addObserver:self
              selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:)
                  name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                object:nil];
[tableView reloadData];
```

There is some problem with the fetchedResultController but I really dont know what kind of.
The error message is:

```
  2013-10-22 10:53:04.750 myAppName[508:c07] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] with userInfo (null)
```

Edit: NSFetcheResultsControllerDelegate:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)inController { 
     [tableView endUpdates]; 
}
```

Comment: Since the exception refers to a delegate method of NSFetchedResultsConroller, it is a good idea to add your implementation of that method to the question.

Comment: - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)inController {
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go with Apple's Core Data template? This creates the fetched results controller lazily, which is the preferred way to deal with data fetching. It is called implicitly when you reload the table via e.g. `objectAtIndexPath`.

To get the FRC from the template, create a new project Master-Detail and copy from the bottom of the master view controller.

I believe your error is resulting from multiple calls to the fetched results controller property. You will notice the subtle difference to your code: that the locally created FRC is assigned to the instance variable `_fetchedResultsController`, while the entire method is the getter for `self.fetchedResultsController`.

Comment: I already had the complete delegate from the master-detail project.              You are right with the local instanced fetch but the error happens in         self.fetchedResultsController = theController;                            and I really dont know why.

Comment: why clear? I have my own method in my main Class (not in the delegate).

Comment: So you don't have the FRC method. Why don't you try that instead of yours?